# Scala function doesn't return the desired result

Tags: string, scala, function

I have a function that (supposedly) returns a `List(String, Int)` that tells the number of times that a word appears in a string, for example:

> "This is a sample string like every other sample string"

The list should have this:

```
List[(String, Int)] = List(("This", 1), ("is", 1), ("a", 1), ("sample", 2), ("string", 2), ...)
```

However I'm getting this result:

```
List[(String, Int)] = List((is,1), (a,1), (sample,1), (string,1), (like,1), (every,1), (other,1), (sample,1), (string,1))
```

The function that I have is this one:

```
def unConstructList(xs: List[String]): List[(String, Int)] = xs match {
    case Nil    => Nil
    case x :: s => List((x, xs.takeWhile(y => y == x).length)) ++ unConstructList(xs.dropWhile(z => z == x))
  }
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `xs.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).toList`

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks. Write this as an answer so I can accept it, please.

Answer (score 3):

`takeWhile` stops on the *first* element that doesn't satisfy the predicate you're passing. From its Scaladoc:

> Takes longest prefix of elements that satisfy a predicate

In this case it means that `xs.takeWhile(y => y == x).length` will return a value greater than `1` only if `x` is both the first and the second item on the list, and in your example - no word appears twice *consecutively* so all words end up with the value `1`.

I'll leave it for you to fix...

Comment: Oh, you're right. Didn't notice that mistake. Thanks.